# How import in Bean Map value from application.yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

This is my application yaml:

```
employees:
         data:
              name surname: name surname
              name surname: name surname
```

This is my class:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "employees")
public class EmployeesMap {

private Map<String, String> data;

public void setData(Map<String, String> data) {
this.data = data;
   }

public Map<String, String> getData() {
 return data;
 }

@Override
public String toString() {
 System.out.println(data.toString());
 return data.toString();

 }
}
```

i have enabled @EnableConfigurationProperties(EmployeeMap.class) in spring boot

i try to run this using:

```java
  public ResponseEntity<Void> readConfig() {
    employeesMap.getEmployees();
    employeesMap.toString();

    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
  }
```

when i try to call toString i have this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "this.employess" is null

Comment: how are you creating the object of EmployeeMap while testing? If its autowired, then probably it should work.

Comment: yes, EmployeeMap is @Autowired in my test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the employees map, you need to define the prefix which is one level up. Something like

```
department:
      employees:
           name:abc
           salary:xxx
```

Then use `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "department")` in EmployeeMap class.